# got error when running stack ghci

Tags: ghci

I ran stack ghci, but always got the following error. How do I fix it? What dose it tell me?

```
$stack ghci
Downloaded lts-10.4 build plan.
AesonException "Error in $.packages.cassava.constraints.flags['bytestring--lt-0_10_4']: Invalid flag name: \"bytestring--lt-0_10_4\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be sure that your current stack version(see `stack --version`) support lts-10.4. Actual version of stack is 1.6.3. If your stack version is older you can upgrade stack by `stack upgrade` or your package manager(if you install stack using it).

https://github.com/fpco/stackage/issues/3132